# UIView - NSURLConnection doesn't call delegates

Tags: ios, uiview, nsurlconnection

I'm using an Objective-C class (`UIView`). In that class I'm calling an `NSURLConnection` (added NSURLConnectionDelegate to .h) When I start the connection, nothing happens. It's not calling its methods. Is it just not possible to call `NSURLConnection` in a `UIView` class or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: have you added <NSURLConnectionDelegate> to object also after creating object of nsurlconnection you should point its delegate to the class object like nsurlconnection a; a.delegate=self; dont miss this two steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not enough to add `<NSURLConnectionDelegate>` to your object's interface declaration, you should explicitly set it as the `NSURLConnection`'s delegate.

Secondly, `UIView` is definitely a wrong candidate as an `NSURLConnection` delegate, because:

- `UIView` is the view part of MVC;
- the view may be unloaded unless you take extra measures like retaining it in the `UIViewController`.

That makes `UIViewController` a better choice as an `NSURLConnection` delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in your UIViewController. Take a look at Apples documentation:

> The UIView class defines a rectangular area on the screen and the interfaces for managing the content in that area. At runtime, a view object handles the rendering of any content in its area and also handles any interactions with that content.[…]

So UIView is not the correct place to do stuff like interaction with a server.

Comment: how about NSObject Class. Can NSObject be NSURLConnectionDelegate?